# Oracle 11: How to use less Decodes in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, oracle11g, decode

Here is my code

```
select decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2) FID1,
       decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2) STRAND_PORT1,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2),
                            decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2)) AS TUBE_COLOR,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2),
                              decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2)) AS STRAND_COLOR,
       decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2) FID2,
       decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2) STRAND_PORT2,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2),
                            decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2)) AS TUBE_COLOR,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2),
                              decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2)) AS STRAND_COLOR
from TABLE(GCOMMS.WIN_SPLICE_CONNECT_REHASH(45600)) sc;
```

I am wanting to check to see which fno is = 12200, fno1 or fno2. Id fno1 is 1200 then I want to show fid1, low1 first and calculate the tube and stand color. basically always wanting to show the 12200 values first. 
I think I can using too many decodes, there has to be a better way.

Comment: I was hoping to do something like this IF FNO1 = 12200 THEN sc.fid1,sc.low1,iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid1,sc.low1) else sc.fid2,sc.low2,iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid2,sc.low2) etc etc

Comment: It would be best to show the names of your tables and columns (only those needed for this query) and what the query is supposed to do. Some of that can be reverse engineered, but it is much easier and more effective for you to share that info directly. (I deleted my other comment since it won't really help much - had to do with CASE expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery, in this way:

```
select FID1,
       STRAND_PORT1,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(FID1, STRAND_PORT1) AS TUBE_COLOR,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(FID1, STRAND_PORT1)) AS STRAND_COLOR,
       FID2,
       STRAND_PORT2,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(FID2,STRAND_PORT2) AS TUBE_COLOR2,
       iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(FID2,STRAND_PORT2) AS STRAND_COLOR2
from (
  SELECT  decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2) FID1,
          decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.fid1,sc.fid2) FID2,
          decode(sc.fno1,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2) STRAND_PORT1,
          decode(sc.fno2,12200,sc.low1,sc.low2) STRAND_PORT2
  FROM TABLE(GCOMMS.WIN_SPLICE_CONNECT_REHASH(45600)) sc
) sc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I believe something like this will be the easiest to understand:

```
select
    sc.fid1 fid1,
    sc.low1 strand_port1,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid1, sc.low1) tube_color,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(sc.fid1, sc.low1) strand_color,
    sc.fid2 fid2,
    sc.low2 strand_port2,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid2, sc.low2) tube_color2,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(sc.fid2, sc.low2) strand_color2 
from TABLE(GCOMMS.WIN_SPLICE_CONNECT_REHASH(45600)) sc
where sc.fno1 = 12200
union all
select
    sc.fid2 fid1,
    sc.low2 strand_port1,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid2, sc.low2) tube_color,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(sc.fid2, sc.low2) strand_color,
    sc.fid1 fid2,
    sc.low1 strand_port2,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.tubecolor(sc.fid1, sc.low1) tube_color2,
    iw_fibertransport_pkg.strandcolor(sc.fid1, sc.low1) strand_color2 
from TABLE(GCOMMS.WIN_SPLICE_CONNECT_REHASH(45600)) sc
where sc.fno2 = 12200;
```

Comment: Not really. You haven't covered all cases. There are four queries to union 1. `sc.fno1 = 12200, sc.fno2 != 12200` 2. `sc.fno1 = 12200, sc.fno2 = 12200` 3. `sc.fno1 != 12200, sc.fno2 != 12200` 4. `sc.fno1 != 12200, sc.fno2 = 12200` Which also need to cover nulls somehow.